# perl fork doesn't execute

Tags: perl, fork

I'm trying to use fork for the first time, so I can redirect the user's web browser and then keep processing.  I looked up the code for using fork, but my child process doesn't execute (i.e., the file doesn't get created).  What am I doing wrong?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl 

if ($pid = fork) { } 
else { 
  close STDOUT(); 
  open(FILE,'>test.txt'); 
   print FILE time; 
  close(FILE); 
  exit(0); 
} 
print "Location: http://mydomain.com/\n\n";
```

Comment: As an aside, you should `use strict; use warnings;` and make your forking have some more robust error checking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`STDOUT()` makes Perl look for a function called `STDOUT`, and not finding one, aborts your child process.

```
$ perl -we 'close STDOUT()'
Undefined subroutine &main::STDOUT called at -e line 1.
```

You just need to say

```
close(STDOUT);
```

or

```
close STDOUT;
```

Even if you can only test this program in a web browser, the error message should still show up in the server error log.

Comment: D'oh!  Thanks, mob, changing STDOUT() to (STDOUT) did the trick!